# Is there anything specific I should do when encountering an SE scraper?

Tags: discussion, copycat-sites, screen-scraping, copyright-infringement

I've seen a lot of scraped and repackaged content in my time, but I just ran across `http://readquestion.com` which seems to have scraped the entire network of sites and re-posted the entire thing without even repackaging it — all SE branding in place.

Is there anything in particular end users can do to report sites like this or mitigate their effects?

Comment: the site is block at my workplace because it's categorized as *"proxy-avoidance-and-anonymizers"* but the url that triggered it is `hidereferrer.net/?http://assigntraffic.com/access.php?group=10_source=readquestion.com_referrer=` considering also it took a minute to get this i say good luck to their shitty speed

Comment: @Memor-X The clone site loads pretty quickly for me directly. My first tip off was that I wasn't logged in!